# Firestore not listing documents which doesn't have fields instead having sub collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an attendance project. So, I have nested documents and collections.  But problem is that:

**Firestore not listing documents that don't have fields. [Firebase db structure Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGAI7.png)
it only listing documents that have fields.**

I am doing this in JavaScript.

```
db.collection("Attendence").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

});

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firestore not listing documents that don't have fields.

That's the expected behavior. The documents that I see listed in italics ("CG1", "CSE A1", and "DG2") are **not** actually documents present in the collection.

The documents that are present in the "Attendence" collection and are writen in italics mean that there exist some subcollections with other documents added under those document IDs.

There is no query that can return those documents since they don't exist. So in other words, you have just reserved some IDs for some documents in that collection and then create a subcollection under it. These kinds of documents are visible in the Firebase Console because you might want to navigate into their subcollections.

One thing to remember, in Cloud Firestore documents and subcollections don't work like filesystem files and directories. If you create a subcollection under a document, it doesn't implicitly create any parent documents. Subcollections are not tied in any way to a parent document.

Comment: Would you please suggest me what should i do now, as Firestore doesn't listing documents which has only collections.

Comment: Simply add a field in each document that contains a single value. In that way you'll be able to read them.